Is it possible to prevent Simple Audio from terminating the program automatically after playback?
I'm programming a command prompt in python and I want to implement native .wav support to my code.
And I went with this - file.py:
# some code before this.
def open_file():
    file_path = input('Type file path (with complete file name): ')
    if file_path.endswith('.wav'):
        wave_obj = simpleaudio.WaveObject.from_wave_file(file_path)
        play_obj = wave_obj.play()
        print('File playing...')
    else:
        print('Unknown file extension.')

main.py:
# some more code before and after this.
    elif input_str == 'file.open':
        file.open_file()
while True:
    cmd_input = input('>> ').casefold()
    cmd_cond_branch(cmd_input)

When I call the function, it plays the selected file and terminates the program like this:

Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

But, I want it to return to main.py.
I tried to add a return at the end of the conditional branch and at the end of the function to exit open_file() - file.py:
# some code before this.
def open_file():
    file_path = input('Type file path (with complete file name): ')
    if file_path.endswith('.wav'):
        wave_obj = simpleaudio.WaveObject.from_wave_file(file_path)
        play_obj = wave_obj.play()
        print('File playing...')
        return
    else:
        print('Unknown file extension.')

# some code before this.
def open_file():
    file_path = input('Type file path (with complete file name): ')
    if file_path.endswith('.wav'):
        wave_obj = simpleaudio.WaveObject.from_wave_file(file_path)
        play_obj = wave_obj.play()
        print('File playing...')
        return
    else:
        print('Unknown file extension.')
    return

# some code before this.
def open_file():
    file_path = input('Type file path (with complete file name): ')
    if file_path.endswith('.wav'):
        wave_obj = simpleaudio.WaveObject.from_wave_file(file_path)
        play_obj = wave_obj.play()
        print('File playing...')
    else:
        print('Unknown file extension.')
    return

But it got worse, exiting directly without displaying ">> ".

The easiest way is to use an early python version, 3.11 for example. If this solution does not fit, you can check the discussion about this issue https://github.com/hamiltron/py-simple-audio/issues/72.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
